# Is there a way to merge multiple properties and then sort via LINQ?

Tags: linq, sorting, merge

I'm working on a class that has URL and FileName fields. An object can either have a URL or a FileName, but can't have both at the same time.

Is there any way to merge these two fields via LINQ and then sort them? I know I can't use

```
OrderBy(i => item.URL).ThenBy(i => item.FileName);
```

because it would just sort the items via URL first and then by their respective FileNames. I need to sort it as if I'm sorting only one field.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy(x => x.URL + x.FileName);
```

You can pad the URL if desired, or do just about any other operation you need.

Comment: wow haha thank you. i didn't know you could do that. Thank you again :)